# How to sequence Dialogs in 'Change' mode of Maintenance Dlg

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have created a few dialog screens for capturing custom information. I have sequenced the dialogs properly based on the Back and Next buttons of my custom dialogs. After the installation of the setup, when the user again launches the setup in Maintenance mode, the 'Change' button appears. In the Change mode, the UI sequence is not proper i.e. the wrong screen comes on clicking the Back or Next buttons. Also, some screens are not to be shown in the Change mode and the complete Dialog UI sequence needs to be set for change mode.

Please advise how can I sequence the DialogUI sequence in 'Change' option of Maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way you schedule the dialogs for new installation. For instance, take a look at the following snippet from WixUI_Mondo preset:

```
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" 
           Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="ChangeButton" Event="NewDialog" 
           Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" 
           Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" 
           Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" 
           Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
```

You can see how CustomizeDlg is set to go next after MaintenanceTypeDlg when you press Change button. Follow the pattern.

If I misunderstood your question, please elaborate further.

Comment: Hi Yan, Thanks for ur reply. But it wasn't what I was looking for. I will elaborate further. I have some user defined dialogs that I am able to sequence for the normal installation. But in the Maintenance Mode, when the user chooses the 'Change' option form the 'Change','Repair' and 'Remove' options, the UI sequence is not correct. Also, some of the custom dialogs are not to be shown in the Change mode. So, basically, I need to trap the 'Change' mode and based on that, I have to set the UI sequence. Hope, I have made it claer this time.

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case you can distinguish the first installation and maintenance mode by Installed property. So, the sequence you already defined for the new install can be "conditioned" with Installed property. For instance, if you'd like a certain dialog to appear only in Maintenance mode, you can add "AND Installed" to your condition for this dialog, and vice versa. This should give you the idea how to change you UI sequence to serve both modes.

Comment: Hi Yan, I tried to condition my dialog as follows: 
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="BlackberryDlg" Order ="4">
        <![CDATA[Not Installed AND Not(REMOVE="ALL") AND(&Mail=3) AND NOT (!Blackberry = 3)]]>
</Publish>
But this didn't work and the dialog comes up in the 'Change' mode. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi Piyush. Hmm... strange. Actually, "NOT Installed" should filter this dialog out in Maintenance mode. Try making this condition wider and leave just "NOT Installed"... Does the dialog still appear in Maintenance mode?